# PHP include directoy: first time using the include

Tags: php, directory, include

I want to include bd.php to my file inside the folder Cidadao. Like this:

[image]

i tried this code:

```
<?php include 'bd.php';?>
```

bus this not working.

this is the [code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ndTIr.png).

Comment: your code is missing

Comment: Include paths are relative to the *current working directory*. You're not telling which script gets invoked first; if it's registo_cidadao.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
<?php include '../bd.php';?>
```

Answer (score 0):

For include any file in php you can use, include, require_once, and require. 
And for include a forward directory file use `include'dir1/dir2/filename.php'`. And for backward directory file use `include'../../filename.php'`. 
Remember, for include you can go  n number of directory forward and backward.